# How to select category on if function

Tags: categories

I am trying to create an automatic post from WordPress to Telegram Channel. It works for everything but I can't select just only one category.

This is the code i am trying to use:

```
function telegram_send_message( $new_status, $old_status, $post, $category_id ) {
  if( $new_status == 'publish' &&  $old_status != 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'post'&& $category_id=='1766') {
    $apiToken = "TOKEN";
    $data = [
      'chat_id' => '@******',
      'text' => "\nRead more: " . get_permalink($post->ID)
    ];
   $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot******/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
  }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'telegram_send_message', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This is not a whole function. How do you recieve `category_id` to check it in if statement?

Comment: you right, edited the post :)

Comment: Interesting. Does this if statement really works? If your task is to post to telegram post which has specific category, I think you need to try to use `&& has_category(1766, $post)` function instead of `&& $category_id=='1766'`.  `transition_post_status` action has only 3 parameters - new status, old status and post object. There is no $category_id parameter, but post object is available for you to check it's categories, as I mentioned with has_category() function for example.

Comment: Yes it works well with Telegram! I have tried your suggestion but it continue to post on Telegram with all categories and not just the 1766. edit: with & has_category('1766', $post) works! :)

Comment: Do you mean it posts a post with all categories attached to this post? Do not understand clearly what are you trying to achieve. When post status changes, you want to post to telegram this post, IF this post has 'post' post type and this post from specific category. You already achieved this. And you want to 'hide' in telegram other categories attached to this post and leave only specific category. Or?

Comment: as said, your solution works well :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Can I put my comment as an answer? I your question is solved, let's remove it from unanswered question list

Comment: Yes, you can, @anton. I would love to see it posted as an answer 

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/), `transition_post_status` action receives only 3 parameters (`$old_status`, `$new_status`, and `$post`).

There is no `$category_id` parameter, but as post object is available for you, you are able to get post category using this post object.

In your case, for the `if` statement, it's better to use [`has_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/) function where you can pass category ID and post object.

> has_category()
> Checks if the current post has any of given category.

So you filter code should look like this:

```php
function telegram_send_message( $new_status, $old_status, $post) {

    //$category_id=='1766' changed to has_category(1766, $post)
    if( $new_status == 'publish' &&  $old_status != 'publish' && $post->post_type == 'post'&& has_category(1766, $post) {
        $apiToken = "TOKEN";
        $data = [
            'chat_id' => '@******',
            'text' => "\nRead more: " . get_permalink($post->ID)
        ];
        $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot******/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
    }

}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'telegram_send_message', 10, 3 );
```